# How to read multiple files to a dataframe whiteout getting the 'killed' error message?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I trying to fetch multiple csv files into a pandas dataframe. The folder is in total 16.6 GB and consists of multiple csv files. When I run this after a while I get a 'Killed' error. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Code:

```py
def fetchFolder(folderPath):
    print('Loading files...')
    all_files = glob.glob(folderPath + "/*.csv")

    li = []
    for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        li.append(df)

    histTrades = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    histTrades = histTrades.set_index('date')
    histTrades.index = pd.to_datetime(histTrades.index, unit='ms')

    return histTrades

fetchFolder(r'/run/media/kobej/B204D33B04D300F1/Work/backtra/data/BTCUSDT')
```

Output

```
Loading files...
Killed
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have at least 16.6GB of available RAM on your computer? You are trying to load all the data into memory, so if you don't have that much RAM available on your computer, it is not possible to do this.

Try to figure out a way where you can do your processing with only a chunk of your data, save the results to disk, and then operate on other chunks.

Another note - if you do have that much RAM available on your computer, you still have to tell your IDE that it is allowed to use so much RAM. There is setting to do this but this fact is irrelevant if you don't have so much available RAM on your computer.

Comment: Yeah my RAM is 16GB. Do you know how I can procces the data in chunks?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here.

Option - 1 :
Use a library to handle large csv like `dask`. Use it as shown below.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv(file_name.csv)
```

Option -2 : Process data in chunks of 'n' rows.

```
   #Process 5000 rows at a time
   chunk_csv = pd.read_csv('fileName.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=5000)  
   df = pd.concat(chunk_csv, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The first option works for me but I'm unable to concat the dask dataframes.

Comment: Dask page with an example to perform concatenation. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-stack.html